# Obtaining images using mediawiki apis

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, web-crawler

Im trying to follow the tutorials from mediawiki

One of the examples they used is
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Albert%20Einstein&prop=images

So I am wondering how would i convert 
File:1919 eclipse positive.jpg
into the actual link to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `imageinfo` property, as mentioned in the docs. E.g.:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:1919%20eclipse%20positive.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iilimit=50&iiend=20071231235959&iiprop=timestamp|user|url

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in Java:
[Get the image link](http://code.google.com/p/gwtwiki/wiki/MediaWikiAPISupport#Example_-_Get_the_image_URL)